# can't access contact list in Outlook 2020 when creating a new email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, contacts, microsoft-outlook-365

can't add a contact from my lengthy Contacts list in Outlook 2020 when creating a new email.  The only addresses I can access are those tied to addresses in my hotmail account, which I have never used and therefore is empty.

Comment: Do you have Contacts in Outlook?  Main Outlook screen lower left, click on Contacts.   In a new Mail, pull down Address Book. Is there an address book with your contacts?

Comment: Can the same operation be successfully achieved in other versions of Outlook? To better understand your issue, please provide us with more information related to your issue(such as screenshots) so that we can do tests in our environment.

Comment: John.  Yes, there is an address book, but it only lists Hotmail contacts (of which I have just one).

Comment: Jeff.  Here's what comes up.

Comment: Jeff.  Sorry.  Can't do a screenshot.  New program (Snagit), and I haven't learned how to use it here.  But the point is, when I select "address" for a new email, the Address Book only lists my Hotmail Address Book.  Not my Contacts.

Comment: Here's a link to my screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/PxCsWjbFnbd (I still haven't figured out how to paste the screenshot in this comment section.